# Chart Aspect ratio not unlocking

Tags: excel, vba

I'm setting up a code that will find the chart object level and from there I want to manipulate size, font, etc, etc. However, I'm running into the problem that the aspect ratio is locked and can't get it moving.
Using the shaperange.lockaspectratio=msofalse . In the locals it changes to False, but when changing height and width it still changes with lock ratio. Looking at the properties on the chart itself in excel, it's also still locked on ratio.
FYI, when I try toggle of print object or locked, that does work.

```
 Sub chart()
Set sc = Selection

'the user selected something, but may be chart area or plot area. So searching for the Chartobject
Dim SelectionArray(10)
Set xx = sc
For x = 1 To 10

    SelectionArray(x) = TypeName(xx)
    Set xx = xx.Parent
    If InStr(LCase(SelectionArray(x)), "chart") Then chartfound = True 'so at least a chart found
Next x
If chartfound = True Then ' to check that a chart is selected (and not other object)
    For x = 1 To 10 'finding the chartobject layer
        If SelectionArray(x) = "ChartObject" Then p = x
    Next x
    Set xx = sc
    For x = 1 To p - 1
        Set xx = xx.Parent
    Next x
    Set sc = xx: Set xx = Nothing 'the SC is now the chart object (so to start from the same basis.

    sc.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
sc.Height = 250
sc.Width = 250

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not as complicated as you've made it. If the user has selected a chart element, then you have an active chart. The chart object is the parent of this chart.

```
Sub ResizeChart()
    Dim chob As ChartObject

    If Not ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
        Set chob = ActiveChart.Parent
        With chob
            chob.Parent.Shapes(chob.Name).LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Height = 250
            .Width = 250
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. Very clear and simplifies my code. However, the issue remains. My chart ratio lock is still there and even adding a .shaperange.lockaspectratio=msofalse to your code doesn’t remove the lock. Any ideas?

Comment: I've inserted a line that unlocks the aspect ratio.

Comment: Thanks Jon, but that line also moves the chob.shaperange.lockaspectratio to msofalse in the locale, but with no effect on actual ratio lock tick box in chart properties and ratio is still locked

Comment: Not at a computer now, but I checked that before posting, and after that line resizing worked as expected.

Comment: I know it should, but something is off. When I create other chart, it all works fine. But the charts I already had, don’t. For now I’ve created a check, resizing to a square and if the aspect ratio didn’t change, it’s locked and the use needs to unlock manually.

Comment: You might have to rebuild that particular chart, then. Sometimes they get corrupted.